# setVariable in node-dbus

Tags: javascript, node.js, dbus

Firstly sorry for my poor English.

This Christmas I received a Thymio. For the fun of it, I have linked my robot with a Raspberry Pi. 
From the Thymio documentation, we can communicate to this robot with DBUS.

I want use Node.js to live remote my Thymio, so I have found node-dbus library and [this script in Python](http://www.lazerduck.co.uk/s/pithymio.py) to help me.

Actually I can get Thymio's variables values with:

```
aseba.GetVariable("thymio-II", "prox.ground.ambiant",function(error,data){});
```

But I can not set variable for move my robot. In Python this script works:

```python
network.SetVariable("thymio-II", "motor.left.target", [300])
```

But in Node.js:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwaky/pxkL57gv/ <== (my full script)

```
aseba.SetVariable("thymio-II", "motor.left.target",[300]);
```

Returns:

```
events.js:72
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
             ^
Error: write EPIPE
   at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
   at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)
```

And this:

```
aseba.SetVariable("thymio-II", "motor.left.target",300);
```

Does not work and doesn't return an error. If you have ideas?

Comment: hm, `aseba.SetVariable("thymio-II", "motor.left.target",[300])` is correct way to call - the signature is "ssaq":  `SetVariable(String nodeName,
String variableName, Array<SInt16> variableData)` do you have any messages just before stack trace you posted?

Comment: unfortunately no, i don't have any error before. I have found the code of function setVariable : 
  
`function (){
    // prevent double callbacks
    if (sent) return;
    sent = true;
    var args = toArray(arguments);
    debug('sending ack %j', args);

    var type = hasBin(args) ? parser.BINARY_ACK : parser.ACK;
    self.packet({
      type: type,
      id: id,
      data: args
    });
  }`
  With "toArray" I think that `aseba.SetVariable("thymio-II", "motor.left.target",300);` should work but no ...

Comment: where is `setVariable` code from? thymio sdk?

Comment: In thymio sdk or in dbus, I don't know Dbus. I have trace the function with `   console.log(aseba.setVariable)    ' for find this code. In node-dbus library there no occurrence of "setVariable". `    sessionBus.getService(destination).getInterface(string,string,function(){}). is the good way to connect me to the Dbus ? There are no other ways ?

Comment: You can auto-generate js code using dbus introspection and https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/bin/dbus2js.js script.

Comment: try to run it with following parameters: `--service=ch.epfl.mobots.Aseba --path=/`

Comment: After more modifications, [this script return](http://jsfiddle.net/p7ay7sao/). I continu to search a solution ...

Comment: Can you try to use generated script? (though  would expect same result). If script is "aseba.js" you would use it like this: https://gist.github.com/sidorares/52b925e3d44a4f4ad06f

Comment: I tried the generated script and thymio don't move ... the script return `   Data:  [ 'DATA',
  '6f72675f667265656465736b746f705f67656e6572616c20383735323234323034203061346334386362613134643961363835396634633864343130663864646461\r' ]    ` when I execute it.